# send xhr post compressed

Tags: javascript, post, gzip

I have a "monitored" application. Every minute the web client do a POST to my services sending a JSON with some data. The json is big (circa 20Kb each time).

Is there a way to send a "compressed" version of the data?
Do I need to do it applicatively?

I'm using jQuery client side, and can send custom headers from the server.

Comment: whats the issue/worry? is the size of the json taking to long to process? is the json unuque every times it's sent?

Comment: it's the bandwith: I have circa 1000000 users, and so the expect traffic in ingress in my application is circa 200Gb / minute....

Answer (score 0):

Well you can also compress data in client side with the library https://github.com/cscott/compressjs. There are multiple methods the choice should be made based on your input data and the resources available in client side.

Besides using the POST request you may try the Websocket connection which should be better for sending larger input data.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the full json post is not required, if it possible to only post the data that has changed sinch that last post then that would greatly reduce the amount of data sent.

if that not possible you could reduce the size of the data posted using [JSONH](https://github.com/WebReflection/JSONH)

From what I've read using web sockets might not use dramatically less bandwidth then http post, but there is a good article here on [optimising websockets](http://buildnewgames.com/optimizing-websockets-bandwidth/)